# Fatal error : Deploying zend application one server to another server

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Why am I getting this error?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with 
message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for 
doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default' in /home/meirc/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:496 
Stack trace: #0 /home/meirc/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src/DoctrineORMModule/Service/EntityManagerAliasCompatFactory.php(44): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('doctrine.entity...') 
#1 [internal function]: DoctrineORMModule\Service\EntityManagerAliasCompatFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'doctrineormenti...', 'Doctrine\ORM\En...') 
#2/home/meirc/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(853): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'doctrineormenti...', 'Doctrine\ORM\En...') 
#3/home/meirc/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(983): Zend\ServiceM in /home/meirc/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 496
```

Comment: because it can't find: doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default

Answer (score 0):

Please check PDO is installed in your server.